# unicodedecodeerror: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 35: invalid start byte tf.gfile.Open

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, tensorflow

I have this error on this part of the code:

```
with tf.gfile.Open(output_frozen_graph_name, "r") as f:
   data = f.read()
   input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)
```

and when I search for solutions all what I found solutions for regular files ,but I'm just new to tensorflow

Comment: (no experience in tensorflow but in encoding problems) What kind of file is this? The typical problem is that file encoding and the system default don't match. Most APIs therefore offer a parameter for `open` functions `encoding=...`. Check tensorflow API.

Comment: yes I already checked for `encoding` and even `error` parameters but they wasn't there, all what I found in the definition was 
`Open = GFile

# TODO(drpng): Find the right place to document these.
_allowed_symbols = [
    'Copy',
    'DeleteRecursively',
    'Exists',
    'FastGFile',
    'GFile',
    'Glob',
    'IsDirectory',
    'ListDirectory',
    'Open',
    'MakeDirs',
    'MkDir',
    'Remove',
    'Rename',
    'Stat',
    'Walk',
]

remove_undocumented(__name__, _allowed_symbols)
`

Comment: Please add your file's encoding and complete traceback to your question. Platform also matters, better add that too.

Comment: This is not how you should read a tensorflow serialized graph. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to bring my `tensorflow` model to an Android app, platform is Nvidia GPU Ubuntu os, I'm working based on what explained here [link](https://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html) this part of the code is from the same tutorial, here is an example of this code at [link](https://gist.github.com/omimo/5d393ed5b64d2ca0c591e4da04af6009#file-prep_model_tf1-py) if there is another source you know of for my main problem that would be great and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it as a binary file. Replace your first line with:

```
with tf.gfile.Open(output_frozen_graph_name, "rb") as f:
```

Comment: Thanks Sri Aurobindo Munagala